# Query about SQL Injection in webpages

Tags: python, sql-injection

Suppose you have a webpage requires you to input your username and password for authentication.

The username name "***abs***" and the password is "***1234abcd***" - you gain entry to the your profile.

But my question is, why is that if I input "***abs' --***" in the username field and no password, it still returns my profile page?

What is happening behind the scenes with the server, SQL and user?

I just cant seem to understand this. Thanks guys for any help.

Comment: Without any code no one can help you. Frameworks? Login Process? Please give us information

Comment: If that is what happens, then the server-side code is horribly broken.

Comment: [little bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @Thilo Yes I'm well aware of that, but my question is why?

Comment: Maybe the reason you don't understand it is that you didn't know that `--` starts a comment in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently substituting the parameters into your SQL string without escaping them. The code presumably looks something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
```

So after your inputs are substituted, the result is:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'abs' --' AND password = ''
```

The quote in the username you entered is terminating the string. Then the `--` starts a comment, so the rest of the query is ignored. So you've transformed the query to just:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'abs'
```

and it no longer checks the password.

Comment: I understand, but how would you protect yourself from this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: It's the first question in the **Related** sidebar. It's one of the most upvoted questions on SO. How could you miss it?